# Elements creating jQuery are looks like undefined at very next line

Tags: jquery, variables, undefined, each

I have appended new elements in an empty "ul" but when I try to access newly appended element from jQuery but its undefined. I am designer so don't get what's going on. I created a simpler version at: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmCFu/15/).

1. I am pulling data from another div and put into list items and final add append it to ul.thumbs ---- This works great and I can see every thing inside the target ul.
2. I tried to get li:first-child a's class name from ul.thumbs but did not succeed. It says its undefined ... while I can see it inside the ul.thumbs.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var catName;
   var thumbLi="";

   $("#cat-nav li a").each(function(){        
       catName = $(this).html();

       $("#portdata li").each(function () {
           itemCat =  $(this).attr("class");

           if(catName==itemCat){
               itemCat = $(".thumb", this).html();
                   thumbLi += "<li>" + itemCat + "</li>";
           }
       });
       $(thumbLi).appendTo("div.box2 ul.thumbs");        
   });

   var firstOne = $(".thumbs li:first-child a").attr("class");
   alert(firstOne);/*Why is it undefined*/
   ```

   });

Comment: You may want to explain what you are trying to achieve and show a sample mark-up, because this code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: is it possible to set-up a jsfiddle for this? It would be useful if we could see the html to go with this.

Comment: can't help without seeing the starting html

Comment: @TommyBs please view simpler version at http://jsfiddle.net/bmCFu/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var firstOne = $(".thumbs li:first-child a").attr("class");`

You are setting the `class` attribute of the selector into `firstOne`, and that selector has no class attached to it.

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvir_azulay/bmCFu/17/) works and will alert the class of the A tag of the first li inside .thumbs

Perhaps you meant to alert the element itself and not its class?

Comment: it has a class, I can see it in firebug the only possible problem is this statement run when each is still running or not run at all, I think there is need of some bind or some thing like this not sure

Comment: @Imran that is impossible. Show us a REAL fiddle with the real mark-up so we won't have to guess stuff based on your other jsfiddle, which is supposedly not the same as the real one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default value for `thumbLi`. The only place where it can ever get a value in that code is here:

```
if(catName==itemCat){
    itemCat = $(".thumb", this).html();
    thumbLi += "<li>" + itemCat + "</li>";
}
```

You need to make sure that before `$(thumbLi).appendTo("div.box2 ul.thumbs");` runs, thumbLi has a value.

Comment: I have added it, its appending but still cant access first element from jQuery

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, you are selecting the class of the `a` element (`$("ul li:first-child a")`), however `addClass` is being performed on each parent `li` (`$("ul li")`).